# Lookup / Vlookup not returning correct value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, lookup

Either I use Lookup or Vlookup, the result is wrong if my lookup value is from a formula.

It is correct if I type the lookup value.  I'm expecting 5 as result, which I was able to get in first row because I typed '80%'.  However in second row, I get 4 when I reference it to the computed 80%:
But I need to have it look up via a formula, any help please?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried evaluating the formula, from `Formula Tab` --> Under `Formula Auditing Group` --> Click `Evaluate Formula` and see what does it show when you are using on computed 80% . Also when using `LOOKUP()` you can use it in this way, `=LOOKUP(G1,A1:C6)` & with `=VLOOKUP(G1,A1:C6,3)`

Comment: Also, i suspect is it due to the rounding, have you checked that ?

Comment: thanks mayukh! I tried extending the decimals and cheking if the 80%s are equal, seemed ok too. will perhaps try to check if roundoff/roundup will solve the issue. and check on evaluate formula too that you mentioned. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

While rounding solved the problem for you, it didn't explain where the problem started.

Judging by your examples matching the correct values when typed and wrong if calculated, I conclude the values in `A1:B6` are not percentages, but text strings. Using round on those solves your problem, since round converts the string to a number (if it can).

See explanation in this screenshot:
[image]